# After doing an SVN ( subversion ) sparse checkout how can I checkout more files

Tags: svn, sparse-checkout

Say I have a repository as such

```
- trunk
    - dir0
        - a.txt
        - b.txt
    - dir1
        - c.txt
        - d.txt
```

then I do a sparse checkout so I only have

```
- trunk
    - dir1
        - c.txt
        - d.txt
```

checked out. I decide I actually do need `trunk/dir0/a.txt` as well
How do I tell SVN to add it to the checkout so that my final checkout
will be

```
- trunk
    - dir0
        - a.txt
    - dir1
        - c.txt
        - d.txt
```